# Can I simplify this for loop with a one-line code?

Tags: python

```
my_dict = {'a':'1', 'b':2, 'c':3}
my_list = ['a','b','d']
            
for element in my_list:
  if element not in my_dict:
     my_dict[element] =1
```

Can this for loop be replaced by a one-line code in Python? I can't use dict or list comprehension to do it.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: Probably, but I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: The for loop is my  try, but can't reduce it to one liner.

Comment: I appreciate that you probably want to learn more python tricks (and see what the language is capable of), but any one liners for this are most likely going to be unreadable or have negative consequences on performance

Comment: @byxor, if that's the case, I would keep it the current form. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a dict into `update()`:

```
my_dict = {'a':'1', 'b':2, 'c':3}
my_list = ['a','b','d']
            
my_dict.update({k:1 for k in my_list if k not in my_dict })

my_dict
# {'a': '1', 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
for element in my_list:my_dict[element] = 1 if element not in my_dict else None;my_dict.pop(element) if my_dict[element] == None else ...
```

Comment: This is too long.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in my_list: my_dict[k] = 1 if k not in my_dict else my_dict[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work the same way.

```
dct = {'a':'1', 'b':2, 'c':3}


dct = {element: 1 if element not in dct else dct[element] for element in list(dct.keys()) + my_list }

print(dct);
```

Comment: @byxor this code is giving me the same result

Answer (score 0):

You could use unpacking to produce a new merged dictionary:

```
my_dict = {**dict.fromkeys(my_list,1),**my_dict}
```

or an in-place update with the get function's default parameter set to 1:

```
my_dict.update((k,my_dict.get(k,1)) for k in my_list)
```